# How can install Flutter Correctly in Windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I use this line in C:\src

> git clone -b stable https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

And in PATH i type this line:

> C:\src\flutter\bin

Then

> flutter doctor

but output is :

[image]

How can i install Flutter correctly?

some error is:

```
Error: 'pub upgrade' still failing after 10 tries, giving up.
Error: Error when reading '.packages': The system cannot find the file specified.

Error: Error when reading '../../bin/cache/flutter_tools.snapshot': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem days ago, what I did is

1. Remove cache folder inside `bin/cache`
2. Run `flutter doctor` again

Also I just cloned the master branch and then run `flutter doctor`

`git clone -b master https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git`

And if it doesn't work, most likely is what @user11945700 is saying, something about Antivirus or Firewall, so I recommend you to disable everything, install it, and then activate again.

Otherwise if you want other version you may use this to dowload [Flutter releases versions](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases)

Another guess, could you install it if you run the prompt shell as administrator?

Comment: @melina Well, the releases link is also on my answer, the remove of the `bin/cache` also, is up to you if you accept my answer as a correct or not :)

Comment: i saw your answer after i solve my problem , but for your link i choose your answer as my question's answer.

Comment: i did  Mr ozᴉʞS :) where are you from/

Answer (score 1):

I use this link

> https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=windows

extract file in C:/src

in

> C:/src/flutter/bin

Run:

> flutter doctor

This link help you to install Flutter:

https://www.aparat.com/v/Da9IN/%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4_%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84_%D9%86%D8%B5%D8%A8_flutter

Answer (score 0):

If in your system antivirus or firewall is there then mostly its due to that. try after suspending antivirus and firewall
 You also have one option directly download stable version from here - https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases